# Javascript confirm delete - if no do not submit form? Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Is there a piece of Javascript that would stop a form submit button from carrying out a function

I am using the CodeIgniter framework which uses MVC pattern.

So when you click the button it calls a controller function which then calls a model function etc.

I tried using various things in Javascript including go back, history go back. Is there anything that will stop any event happening?

Here is my code:

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Delete Record?")
    if (answer)
    {

    }
    else
    {       //reloads current page - however it still continues to function
        window.redirect("http://localhost/midas/index.php/control_panel/user_records");
    }
}
```

It still continues to do the function if I say "Cancel". Is there any way to stop the browser?

This is my php code:

```
//js = is a variable which stores the javascript code
echo form_submit('view','View', $js);
```

This creates html output like so:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="confirmation()" value="View" name="view">
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the javascript event in your form tag and use `onSubmit` instead of `onClick`, also you don't need an external js for this.

```
<form action="url/to/form" onSubmit="return confirm('are you sure?')">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the button which is causing the POST.. then put a function call on the OnClick event for that button.  Have that function return true to continue with the POST or return false to cancel the action.

Answer (score 2):

```
function confirmation() {
  var answer = confirm("Delete Record?")
  if (answer) {

  } else {
    //reloads current page - however it still continues to function
    return false;
  }      
}
```

Maybe returning false to the method will stop the form submit. Depends how you're calling the confirmation function.

Comment: Nope still continues, should I integrate my javascript with my php function? At the moment the javascript just posts a message like you see in the code.

Comment: How do you call the confirmation method?

Comment: It is `<input type="submit" onclick="return confirmation()" value="View" name="view">` You forget the return.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return false;` at the end of your `else` statement after your `window.redirect`.

**Edit:**

After looking at your `onclick` event code I would suggest changing your `onclick` to look something like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="confirmation(); return false;" value="View" name="view">
```

Comment: can simply write `onclick="return confirm('question?');"` since the native `confirm()` method returns a boolean based on the user selection. on user cancel, the click event will return false and prevent the form action. op's original function `confirmation()` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

using codeigniter form helper it would be :

```
echo form_open('url/to/form', array('onsubmit'=>'return confirm(\'use triple escape to escape special chars like \\\'quotes\\\'. \')'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a view helper and do something to this effect

```
function delete_button($id)
{
  $button = form_open(current_url().'/delete');
  $button .= form_hidden('id', $id);
  $button .= form_submit(array(
    'name' => 'delete', 
    'onclick' => "return confirm('are you sure you wish to delete?');"
  ), 'Delete');
  $button .= form_close();
  return $button;
}
```

then in my view, i'll use `<?= delete_button($row->id) ?>` to render the necessary form and submit (delete) button code. since the javascript `confirm()` method returns a boolean, we can simply just `return` the method since it'll return `false` when the user cancels on the confirmation dialog and naturally a click event that `returns false;` will prevent it from proceeding to the form action.

Answer (score -1):

PHP code:

```
$attributes = array('id' => 'formId','onsubmit'=>'return validate()');
echo form_open('controller', $attributes);
```

where validate() is the javascript function being called on submit.
And if it return false, form will not submit. :-)